# Get a string sequence from a node-set in XPath 1.0

Tags: xpath

I'm using XPath 1.0 to parse an HTML file and I want to get a string sequence from a node-set. First I select a node-set (eg: `//div`) and then I want the string-value of each node of the set. I've tried with `string(//div)` but it only returns the string-value of the first node in the set.

Example:

```
<foo>  
    <div>  
         bbbb<p>aaa</p>  
    </div>  
    <div>  
         cccc<p>aaa</p>  
    </div>  
</foo>
```

I expect a result like `('bbbbaaa', 'ccccaaa')` but I only get `'bbbaaa'`

Answer (score 4):

**In XPath 1.0 the ["string-value of a node-set"](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) is by definition the string value of the first node in the node-set**.

**In XPath 2.0** the following expression produces a sequence of the string values of all `div` elements in an XML document:

```
//div/string(.)
```