# Does libxml2 support XPath 2.0 or not?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, libxml2, xpath-2.0, interface-implementation

I've tried to use the `XPath 2.0` exp `//span/string(.)` in `libxml2`, but it doesn't work.
So, my question is: does `libxml2` support `XPath 2.0` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know -- not. The prevailing majority of XPath 2.0 implementations are part of XSLT 2.0 processors or XQuery processors.

Answer (score 19):

According to [this 2007 email](http://www.mail-archive.com/xml@gnome.org/msg04082.html) from the maintainer of libxml2, libxml2 does not, and will not, support XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

you might be interested in [an XPath 2.0 extension to libxml2](http://www.explain.com.au/libx/)  - however, 2 caveats apply: it's work in progress and it's free for non-commercial use only.

hope this helps,

best regards, carsten

ps:
i am neither affiliated with the guys working on libx nor have i any personal experience on using it or knowledge beyond the info from their website.

Comment: links are dead :) do you know where can i download this library?

Answer (score 0):

> Libxml2 implements a number of existing standards related to markup languages:

```
the XML standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml
Namespaces in XML: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/
XML Base: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/
RFC 2396 : Uniform Resource Identifiers http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt
XML Path Language (XPath) 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath
HTML4 parser: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/
XML Pointer Language (XPointer) Version 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr
XML Inclusions (XInclude) Version 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/
ISO-8859-x encodings, as well as rfc2044 [UTF-8] and rfc2781 [UTF-16] Unicode encodings, and more if using iconv support
part of SGML Open Technical Resolution TR9401:1997
XML Catalogs Working Draft 06 August 2001: http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/spec-2001-08-06.html
Canonical XML Version 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n and the Exclusive XML Canonicalization CR draft http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n
Relax NG, ISO/IEC 19757-2:2003, http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/relax-ng/spec-20011203.html
W3C XML Schemas Part 2: Datatypes REC 02 May 2001
W3C xml:id Working Draft 7 April 2004
```

Since libxml2 supports XPath 1.0, the syntax is incorrect:

```
//span/string(.)
```

Should be:

```
string(//span/.)
```

For clarification, the `string` method is part of XPath 1.0 as well. For future reference:

- libxml2 supports XPath 1.0
- Objective-C supports XPath 2.0 via the `nodesForXPath` method of NSXMLNode in GNUStep/NextStep

> The Cocoa implementation uses XPath 2.0, which is a World Wide Web Consortium recommendation.

**References**

- [NSXML Concepts: XML Glossary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/XMLGlossary.html)
- [NSXML Concepts: Querying an XML Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/QueryingXML.html)
- [NSXMLNode: nodesForXPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLNode/nodesForXPath:error:)
- [GNUStep: NSXMLNode Class Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnustep/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSXMLNode.html)
- [GalaXquery](http://galax.sourceforge.net/doc/commandline.html)
- [PsychoPathXPathProcessor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PsychoPathXPathProcessor)
- [CoreServicesLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW5)
- [libxml, a.k.a. gnome-xml](http://xmlsoft.org/xml.html)

Comment: I don't think this is right; at least, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2821094/179332) indicates that `//span/string(.)` is valid XPath 2.0.

Comment: @AdamSpiers I answered this question: `So, my question is: does libxml2 support XPath 2.0 or not?`