# Using meta characters for string search in XML using XML::LibXML in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xml-libxml

I am reading a XML file and want to replace the XPath in "print" as "@href="*?releaseStatus=RELEASED" so that I will make it generic to get the first occurrence of the instance. How can I achieve that?

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("type_book.xml");

for my $chapter_node ($doc->findnodes('/book/contents'))
{
print $chapter_node->findvalue('locator[@href ="/book/isbn/979-0-4444-1000-17/book-part/chapter/bk444444ch1?releaseStatus=RELEASED"]/@title');
}
```

XML File:

```
<book>
<contents>
<locator href="/book/isbn/979-0-4444-1000-17/book-part/chapter/bk444444ch1?  releaseStatus=RELEASED" role="http://www.abc.org/roles/book-part-locator" title="Photonic crystal light-emitting sources">
</locator>
<locator href="/book/isbn/979-0-4444-1000-17/book-part/chapter/bk444444ch1?releaseStatus=RELEASED&amp;format=pdf" role="http://www.abc.org/roles/book-part-pdf-locator" title="Photonic crystal light-emitting sources">
</locator>
<locator href="/book/isbn/979-0-4444-1000-17/book-part/chapter/bk444444ch1?releaseStatus=RELEASED&amp;format=epub" role="http://www.abc.org/roles/book-part-epub-locator" title="Photonic crystal light-emitting sources">
</locator>
</contents>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good enough?

```
locator[contains(@href, "?releaseStatus=RELEASED")]/@title
```

---

Using XPath 2 functions (Not sure if supported by XML::LibXML)

```
locator[fn:matches(@href, "^.*(\?|&)releaseStatus=RELEASED(&|$)")]/@title
```

You might need to associate `fn` with `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions`.

Comment: It should always return for "releaseStatus=RELEASED" only, not for all like "releaseStatus=RELEASED&amp" etc.

Comment: adjusted for new info

Comment: @ikegami: Are you sure about libxml2 supporting XPath 2? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586896/does-libxml2-support-xpath-2-0-or-not

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, I know it supports some for sure; I just don't know the extent.