# How to find xpath version of software?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xpath

I've been using xmllint and just came across that it seems to be using the xpath 1.0 specification and I'm using a function that requires at least an xpath 2.0 implementation. There's xpath in my shell as well which I believe is a Perl implementation but it has no command line option for any version information.

Is there some standard way to find out what version of the xpath specifications an xpath implementation is written around?

This is for a bash shell script I am writing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does libxml2 support XPath 2.0 or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586896/does-libxml2-support-xpath-2-0-or-not)

Comment: Use xidel instead of xmllint and see if it works.

Comment: @nullPointer Partially, I was hoping/looking for some sort of an xpath command or some standard way to get the version being used but in lieu of that at least it gives information about what versions are available in what software.

Comment: I have found one thing out which is xQuery seems to have come along at the same time as xpath 2.0 and it seems that xpath is now considered a subset of xQuery in many implementations so rather than look for versions of xpath I find I get useful results just by looking for xQuery.