# XPath getting text from all elements that match XPath query

Tags: php, xpath

I am having a lot of difficulty constructing a query that will return all the text from all the elements below in one string *(assume all other elements on the page contain text as well and are not `span` or `div` elements)*.

Note: Because I am using the PHP XPath engine, I am forced to use a solution that is XPath 1.0.

HTML

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
<div>!!!</div>
<span>This</span>
<span>is</span>
<span>cool</span>
```

XPath

```
normalize-space(//*/div | //*/span)
```

Desired output:

`Hello World!!! This is cool`

I appreciate any suggestions. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `normalize-space()` Xpath 1.0 function does work on a string - not on a node-set. In your example code you have a node-set as it's first parameter:

```
 normalize-space(//*/div | //*/span)
```

In such a case, the [*"string-value of a node-set"*](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) is the string value of the first node. So what you do is not fitting to your needs.

To the very best of my knowledge it is not possible to achieve what you're looking for with a single XPath 1.0 query *alone*. It's possible with the help of PHP however creating the string you're looking for by registering a PHP function that does what you're looking for.

See as well:

- [`DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions()` — Register PHP functions as XPath functions](http://php.net/domxpath.registerphpfunctions)
- [How to filter a select nodeset with a PHP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12960211/367456)
- [Get a string sequence from a node-set in xpath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2819540/367456)

Answer (score 1):

You already have space between the elements, so there's no need to add any, as long as you include it in what you select. If you pass a node set to something that expects a string, XPath converts the node set to a string by just concatenating together all descendant text nodes, in document order. So if the context node is the parent of all these `div` and `span` elements, the simplest expression is just

```
normalize-space(.)
```

Comment: indeed, much simpler!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried `(/*/div | //*/span)/normalize-space(.)` with no success and I also the following query `normalize-space(.)` returns a lot of unwanted text, is there a way to target only a specific type of element to grab the normalized-space-text from?

Answer (score 0):

This works for xpath 2.0:

```
string-join(/*/text(), ' ')
```

Tested [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi), prints:

```
Hello World !!! This is cool
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I am using PHP's XPath engine which unfortunately does not suport XPath 2.0.

Comment: Ok, your are welcome. I'll just leave it here, may be it'll be helpful to someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using EXSLT string extensions with lxml (Python)
http://www.exslt.org/str/str.html

```
str:replace(str:concat(//text()), "\n", " ")
```

or even simpler

```
normalize-space(str:concat(//text()))
```

Tested in Python shell

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc="""<div>Hello</div>
... <div>World</div>
... <div>!!!</div>
... <span>This</span>
... <span>is</span>
... <span>cool</span>"""
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(doc, parser=lxml.html.HTMLParser())
>>> root.xpath('str:replace(str:concat(//text()), "\n", " ")', namespaces={"str": "http://exslt.org/strings"})
'Hello World !!! This is cool'
>>> root.xpath('normalize-space(str:concat(//text()))', namespaces={"str": "http://exslt.org/strings"})
'Hello World !!! This is cool'
>>>
```